# Quick Method for Sorting User Defined Classes

Tags: python, class, sorting

I have a class in python where one of the instance variables is an integer. Now when I have a few of those in a list if I call the sort method on that list I want them to sort by that integer instance variable. Is there a way to quickly/efficiently do that or should I just define all the comparison methods in the class I made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from operator import attrgetter

print sorted(your_objects, key=attrgetter('the name of your int'))
```

Or:

```
your_list.sort(key=attrgetter('the name of your int'))
```

You can also use `lambda` instead of `operator.attrgetter`:

```
your_list.sort(key=lambda L: L.your_int)
```

Comment: Personally I prefer the `lambda`.

Answer (score 0):

"... or should I just define all the comparison methods in the class I made."

You can use the `functools` module:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html

to automate part of this - define the less than and equality methods in your class and then use the total_ordering class decorator to generate the rest. See the example provided for total_ordering in the docs and you can't go wrong!

I think this is a better approach then providing the `key=blah` in every case in your code where you want to sort your class instances.